# Change image displayed in an imageView

Tags: android, imageview

I want to have an imageView change the image it is displaying to a different one from my drawables. All the other methods that I have found an tried result in the app crashing. There 2 imageViews in the activity and I want to be able to change what both display, but independently from each other. I am new to Java scripting, so the simplest and most basic answer will help me the most.

Here is my XML:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/a"
    android:contentDescription="@string/a_mode"
    android:onClick="startAMode" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/p"
    android:contentDescription="@string/p_mode"
    android:onClick="startPMode" />
```

Here is my current Java script:

```
public class SelectorActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_selector);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.selector, menu);
    return true;
}

public void startAMode(View view) {
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.adown);
}
```

}

This doesn't work:

```
    public void startAMode(View view) {
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.adown);
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: and your exception stacktrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First define the Drawable, then set it in an ImageView.

```
Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.id.imageView1);
img.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);
```

Comment: This doesn't work:
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
Drawable annoybutton = getResources().getDrawable(R.id.imageView1);
img.setImageDrawable(annoybutton);
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.annoydown);
It still crashes upon tapping the image. Is the above code incorrect?

Comment: Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.NAMEOFIMAGE); Do this, it will be all right

Answer (score 1):

Your method should be "public void startAMode(){...}" and you need to call it from on onCreate() like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_selector);

    startAMode();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
img = ( ImageView )findViewById( R.id.imageView1 );
Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.imagename);
img.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Which folder are you using for images src? I think the problem is in drawable folder. Create it manually without hdpi, ldpi and other extensions and put images into it